# keyboard plugged but not typing

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard

I plugged the keyboard Windows detects it but I can't type I think this is driver issue but it is up to date I tried almost everything unplug/plug kbd, restart PC disable/enable keyboard, update driver change USB port, when booting I can press delete and enter to BIOS but I can't login into OS and see Welcome

I have this message

> Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. The driver may be corrupted or missing   code 39
>
> Unable to load device driver
>
> %hs device driver could not be loaded. Error status was 0x%x

cable USB keyboard modecom mc 9005

## update

in Recovery mode it works I can type password with the keyboard so it seems that this is OS problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I did from **Advanced settings**->Recovery->Refresh PC   helped!

Keyboard works

Answer (score 0):

1. Try plugging into a USB 2.0 port on the computer
2. In BIOS make sure all your USB ports are set to enabled
3. Leave the keyboard unplugged until after windows boots then try using
4. Unplug computer and push power button several times to drain any remaining power in it and try re-using
5. Disable fast-boot/quick-boot in BIOS

Also are any lights displaying on the keyboard? Does your numpad or capslock light come on?

Comment: yes num lock comes with green LED light

Comment: Is your mouse working ?

Comment: yes mouse works

Comment: updated with error message

Comment: Could you try getting the driver manually installed, from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjUq7z18ZLSAhXG64MKHc_YB6EQFggmMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmodecom.com%2Fen%2Fdownloads%2F&usg=AFQjCNEeB6dKaQS1JlL_oP1-F5Qw4Mxr7A) perhaps?

Comment: updated i wrote what i noticed